# Div With Negative Margin and Background Color Not Showing In Flexbox From Outside

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to have a div with negative margin impinge upon a flexbox from outside and below the flexbox including its background color. In the attached snippet, the title "Up Up and ..." has a white background that is not showing. The position of the title itself is fine. If you comment out flex-row, you'll see it appear in the lower div. Is this possible to do with flex-box?

I've checked other flex-box negative margin posts. They deal with margins within the flexbox. I wouldn't be doing this if it wasn't a hard requirement of converting a fixed page layout into a responsive one. In addition, the real world project uses an image in the left child.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.left-child {
  height: 16em;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.right-child {
  height: 16em;
  background-color: orange;
}

.negative {
  margin-top: -4em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  background-color: white;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.mf6 {flex: 0 0 50%;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row parent">
  <div class = "mf6 left-child">
    <h1>Left Header Content</h1>
  </div>
  <div class = "mf6 right-child">
    <h1>Right Header Content</h1>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="negative">
  <h1>Up Up and Away, this is really long in order to make it into the second section. It should have a white background</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: if you add `position:relative;` to **.negative** you should see the white background

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa, if you add this as an answer, I'll accept it. It didn't think there was a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `position:relative;` to **.negative**

here it is:

```
.parent {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.left-child {
  height: 16em;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.right-child {
  height: 16em;
  background-color: orange;
}

.negative {
  margin-top: -4em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  position:relative; // this line
  background-color: white;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.mf6 {flex: 0 0 50%;}
```

Comment: For others that come here for the answer, it would be helpful if you explained what you did. They might not see your comment attached to the question. Just adding your comment to the answer would suffice.